# How to break out of this loop?

Tags: python

Write a Python program to guess a number between 1 to 9. Go to the editor
Note : User is prompted to enter a guess. If the user guesses wrong then the prompt appears again until the guess is correct, on successful guess, user will get a "Well guessed!" message, and the program will exit.
Edit:- i want to print a message everytime a wrong number is input. However i am getting that message even if i write the correct number.

```
target_num = 3
guess_num = ""

while target_num != guess_num:
    guess_num = int(input('Guess a number between 1 and 10 until you get it right : '))
    print("wrong guess")

print('Well guessed!')`
```

Comment: first edit code and format it

Comment: The `while` continues execution until the *end* of the block. So even after the correct value is entered, the `print` is still executed then the block exits.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use to `break` keyword like so:

```
target_num=3 
while True:
    guess_num = int(input('Guess a number between 1 and 10 until you get it right : ')) 
    if guess_num == target_num:
        break
    print("wrong guess") 
print('Well guessed!')
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to use `break` you could use:

```
target_num=3 
guess_num=""
while guess_num != target_num:
    guess_num = int(input('Guess a number between 1 and 10 until you get it right : ')) 
    if guess_num != target_num:
        print("wrong guess") 
print('Well guessed!')
```